# If $f$ integrable, show |$f$| also integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I am solving the following problem:

(1) Suppose that f: [a,b] → R is integrable. Prove that the function |f|: [a,b] → R which sends x to |f(x)| is also integrable, and

(2)$$|\int_a^b f(x)dx|  \leq \int_a^b |f(x)|dx$$

I have solved the first part, but I'm having trouble solving (2), the second part and could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: For the correct formulation of (b), consider that $\left|\sum x_i \right| \leqslant \sum |x_i|$ by the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that $|f|$ is integrable you can use the fact that $$-|f(x)| \le f(x) \le |f(x)|$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and the monotonicity of the integral to deduce that $$-\int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx \le \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \le \int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx.$$

Once you convince yourself that the inequalities $|t| \le M$ and $-M \le t \le M$ are equivalent you'll have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For now, suppose that $f(x)$ is above the $X$-axis for $[a, c]$ and is below the $X$-axis for $[c, b]$ where $c\in[a, b]$, therefore, we can say:
$$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}|f(x)|dx = \int_{x=a}^{x=c}|f(x)|dx + \int_{x=c}^{x=b}|f(x)|dx$$
$$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}|f(x)|dx = \int_{x=a}^{x=c}f(x)dx - \int_{x=c}^{x=b}f(x)dx$$
And as we know that $f(x)$ can be integrated in $[a, b]$, hence, we can also say, without the loss of generality, that $|f(x)|$ can also be integrated in $[a, b]$.